# Is it possible to manage/locate galaxy smart tags from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore, find-my-iphone, geolocation

I can see a galaxy smart things app from Samsung in the iOS app store, but I'm wondering if there is actually any way to view the locations of one's smart tags from an iPhone as I can't find any indication to that effect online which makes me inclined to think that the answers no, however I did just want to confirm.